# When are smart pointers' memory cleared on calling execv() in a program?

Tags: c++, memory, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, execv

I was trying to understand when the memory owned by shared (smart) pointers are cleared on calling `execv()` from the code.

---

Assume the following code:

```
#include <memory>

class Test { public: ~Test() { std::cout << "Test destroyed."; } };

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<Test> p = std::make_shared<Test>();
  std::shared_ptr<Test> q = p;

  p.reset();

  // Call execv().
  execv("/bin/program", "/bin/program");

  // This code will never be executed, because execv() replaces the current process image.
  // Will the memory pointed to by q be cleared?
  return 0;
}
```

---

On calling `execv("/bin/program", "/bin/program");` the current process image is replaced with the new process image.
My question is will the memory owned by the shared pointer be cleared or not when the new process starts or should we call `q.reset()` explicitly before calling `execv("/bin/program", "/bin/program");`?

I tried looking at the documentation of `execv()` but could not find any mention of smart pointers.

Comment: Basically you leave it up to the OS to cleanup the mess when it replaces your process because Test's destructor will not get called. So if you want to play nice you have to find another whay to execute the other binary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syscalls like `execve` or the computer catching fire are an "out of context" problem for C++. When you call `execve`, the program flow transitions to the kernel. The kernel completely reinitializes the memory space and the original program *does not get a chance to run again*. The smart pointer and the memory it used to manage simply ceases to exist.

If you wanted to use the smart pointer's release action to perform side effects that are visible outside of the program (eg file or network I/O), release them by hand before calling `execve`.

Answer (score 3):

From C++ perspective you are simply making a call. It is not aware that the process is being replaced with another one. And it won't treat that call differently from any other call. You are not leaving scope, so no destructor will run. In particular, shared pointers won't have opportunity to finalize themselves.

The memory will be wiped out (because of how execv works), but not in a graceful way. In particular if you expect some action to run on destruction then you have to finalize stuff manually. This is especially important if you are dealing with resources outside of the process.

Also, you won't find anything about smart pointers in execv docs. It is part of [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) C bindings, which is a C library. While technically it can be used by C++ (because of its compatibility with C), it is not aware of non-C features of C++. Execv (and POSIX in general) doesn't even know what smart pointers are.

Comment: `execv` is a system call, not a C function

Comment: @M.M no, it is a libc function declared in C header file unistd.h. The fact that it does a syscall is irrelavant.

Comment: It's not in the C standard, and both C and C++ language implementations can call functions in libc.  (For systems that have a libc). It's not particular to any language

Comment: @M.M you are nitpicking now. The libc api is written in C. It is not aware of anything beyond C, like non-C features of C++ or anything else.

Comment: The `libc` API is aware of the operating system. A lot beyond the C standard. @M.M is correct here, and this is not 'nit-picking'.

Comment: @user207421 api is not aware of the operating system. Its just a bunch of header files. The implementation is aware of the operating system, but not declarations. Api doesn't do anything, its just is. The api was defined in C, not in C++. There's nothing more to this.

Comment: It's not a C function or a system call, it's a API entry point (with C interface from the system C lib provided for convenience) for POSIX compliant systems. One doesn't need C or C++ to call it, one doesn't even need to "call" it (you can invoke the syscall directly in assembly).

Comment: I just want to say that: "`execv` is not a part of C++, and therefore does not know (or document) anything about C++ features like smart-pointers" is a very nice and clear point as I read it - and I agree that any discussion of what `execv` then *is* is nitpicky and secondary to the point of "it is NOT C++".

Comment: @TerenceSimpson the POSIX standard document explicitly says "Access to these services has been provided by defining an interface, using the C programming language" and in another place "The system interfaces and header definitions are written in terms of the standard C
language as specified in the ISO C standard." POSIX apis are in C. While it is possible to access them in different ways (e.g. direct assembly or C compatible languages), the only well defined way in the POSIX standard is through C.

Comment: In fact, you can even find this in the POSIX document: *"POSIX.1 is, for historical reasons, both a specification of an operating system interface, shell and utilities, and a C binding for that specification. Efforts had been previously undertaken to generate a language-independent specification; however, that had failed, and the fact that the ISO C standard is the de facto primary language on POSIX and the UNIX system makes this a necessary and workable situation"*. I hope this ends this discussion.

Comment: I've slightly modified wording in my answer to reflect that.